# Can Nessus scanner be used behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, vulnerability-scanners, nessus

Is it possible use Nessus behind a proxy like Burp or OWASP ZAP? I tried to configure it in *Web Proxy Settings*, but it didn't work. I need to see all request/response that are performed during the assesment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy functionality in nessus is for traffic such as plugin updates etc.

This is not a supported feature to use a proxy server for scan-traffic, but you can route web traffic transparently to your attack-proxy.

Take a look at [How do you capture ALL the traffic from an Android app?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60726/how-do-you-capture-all-the-traffic-from-an-android-app/139639#139639)

The same method should be possible here.