# Certificate warning with NoxPlayer and OWASP ZAP

Tags: android, zap

I have tried to dip my toe into android hacking. I followed this helpful article [on Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/android-mobile-penetration-testing-lab-dfb8ceb4efbd).

I'm using NoxPlayer emulator and OWASP ZAP as proxy. I have rooted the device, imported certificate from ZAP, changed the file extension to .cer . I have developer mode and have I managed to connect to the device from the host machine with adb and even start frida server on the device, and even got ssl pinning bypass working.

Everything seamed to be working, but it's not. When I go to some website I get a certificate warning. So I am not sure if I am missing something or this is the way it supposed to be (I am using Zap on my normal browser every day without problem).

I also noticed some functionalities of the app I am testing are not working (it says that I am not connected to internet).

I am including some pictures for better illustration.
I also found this [article](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60726/how-do-you-capture-all-the-traffic-from-an-android-app?rq=1) that was trying to figure out the same and the answer the (6years ago) was that you cant capture all the traffic, as every application is specific about how it may handle the certificates (did that change by any chance?).
How do I fix this?

[image: trusted cert]
[image: the error]

Comment: It sounds like your pinning bypass isn't working? I think you need to add more info about the certificate warning and what you discovered in the packet traces an Zap log.

Comment: @schroeder I have added some pictures for clarification, hope it helps. I do not how to get packet traces from Zap but i will look into that. If it helps I used this https://codeshare.frida.re/@akabe1/frida-multiple-unpinning/ script for the unpinning with frida, and it seamed that it was working. As I said I got the traffic from the app through to ZAP.