# How can Kazakhstan perform MITM attacks on all HTTPS traffic?

Tags: tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority

There is now [MITM on HTTPS traffic in Kazakhstan](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1567114).

But for MITM to work, other than installing the certificate, there has to be someone proxying the request, right? Will that role be played by the ISPs?

Say I want to connect to Facebook. Does the proxy spoof Facebook's certificate?
How does that work?

Accessing Facebook under the MITM scheme and looking at the certificates from the browser, would the MITM certificate be visible?

Comment: It works like this: the CA once installed it allows decryption of your secure traffic no matter the destination.

Comment: So how did users in Kazakhstan end up with that cert inside their browser/OS trust store?

Comment: @Navin As explained in the link, ISPs contacted end-users and told them to download and install that certificate. I don't understand Kazakh, but my guess is that they tell users to do that to make the error messages go away which now appear on all HTTPS websites.

Comment: So glad that this is one problem I do NOT have.

Comment: [How is it possible to do TLS through proxy without anyone noticing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/115762/29925), [Man-in-the-middle Blue Coat proxy SSL or what?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33976/29925), [How is intercepting my own HTTPS traffic possible?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/191759/29925), [How does SSL Proxy server in company work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/133254/29925), [How to prevent proxy server from HTTPS packet inspection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/136503/29925), etc.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### How does that work?

They seem use an ***[In-the-middle SSL Bump proxy](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump)***.

- First, it works as a *transparent proxy*, meaning it will silently redirect all *HTTPS* traffic to *SSL Bump proxy servers*.
- You have to install and accept the proxy's *Certificate Authority* cert to make this work.
- Once done, each SSL connection is made from your host to the *SSL Bump Proxy* with an on-the-fly generated certificate reproducing real certificate properties. Have a look at [image: ![KazakMitm From https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1567114]  (And care about certificate ***issuer*** and ***start of validity*** timestamp)
- Then, the proxy pretends to be the targeted website (Facebook) to receive your request,
- it reproduces your request (pretending to be yourself) to the real website
- It receives an answer from the real website.
- Now, the proxy is able to store the request and/or answer if built to do so.
- Then it forwards the answer to your browser.

#### Will that role be played by the ISPs?

Probably yes, but it could be located anywhere before the traffic leaves the country.

#### Would the MITM certificate be visible?

Yes, as these certificate are mostly generated *on-the-fly*, have a look at the "Validity ***Not before***" (in this case approx 1 day before the request) and "*Certificate Issuer*" (in this case: **`No data`** instead of **`DigiCert Inc`**).

To check this, go to different websites and check each cert. If you always see the same *`Issuer`*, and for each site you reach you always see a *`Not before`* with the same interval from your 1st request...

Take some references: Google's issuer is `Google Trust Services`, Facebook uses `DigiCert Inc` and so on... Take your own references.

For a website you know well (ie you know if and when the SSL cert could be updated), you could use *`fingerprints`* to verify certificates.

### What to do

Go to your browser's *`config/preference`* -> *`security`* -> *`show/manage SSL certificates`*  and *`delete/drop/untrust`* unwanted certificates (in this case, search for ***`No data`*** or ***`KZ`***).

Of course, once this is deleted, you will not be able to reach the internet through ***this*** network!

You may try to use some VPN (public or private), but I don't know how *other connections than HTTP(s) are treated*. Even *VPN over HTTP(s)* may work until official proxies sysadmin will see your encrypted stream...

You could connect to the Internet in alternative ways (satellite, radio frequencies, private wires...).

Use alternative hardware and be careful about your activities while you're connected to *this network*.

#### About picture:

This picture was found at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1567114 and edited to underline

- In blue: At top, date of picture, I suppose near the connection and screenshot. On the right, the ***`Not before`*** which seems to exist just 24 hours before the screenshot. (I assume the whole picture was done some minutes after the last cert screenshot, which was done some seconds after the connection, but I'm not sure.)
- In orange: the *`certificate issuer`* - on the left side, the *real* issuer and on the right side, there is *`No data`* which is more than suspect!
- In red: this mark was already present before my edit - you could see *`KZ`*  instead of *`US`*, but this field could be faked too!

So ensuring the same *Certificate Authority* is not used on radically different domains is a good indication. (IE: If you see the same *issuer* when reaching Microsoft, as Google or Facebook, then there is something wrong!)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96632/discussion-on-answer-by-f-hauri-how-can-kazakhstan-perform-mitm-attacks-on-all).